# How many instances of omxplayer are possible with 1xFHD and 2-3 smaller videos being played at same time?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

I'd like to have the following setup:

- Background video in seamless loop
- preload x videos and keep them paused or in memory until needed
- x dependent on videos in certain folder (create library)
- trigger video based on filename by a serial command (2x 1byte)
- keep background video running (FHD or 720p, depending on performance of pi 3 B+)
- play triggered video on top, should be played instantly or with very low delay

How could i achieve this the optimal way?

Greetings,
Dom